# How do I mix synchronous and asynchronous requests in Spring MVC?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

(I'm asking this question with the intent of answering it. I asked it on the Spring forums a couple of months ago, and I found the solution through experimentation shortly after. But I'm posting it here in case someone else hits the same scenario and because I was told to.)

I have a Spring MVC endpoint `/work` whose processing is IO bound and can take a few seconds to complete. Enter Servlet 3 asynchronous requests and Spring MVC [asynchronous request processing](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-async). I can return a `Callable<Foo>` or `DeferredResult<Foo>` and free up my servlet container threads to do something useful while that processing is happening.

Now it's likely that other users will make the identical request. There's no point repeating the work that was done, so I'm going to cache the result of the work the first time it completes, and want to return that cached result. So now, the exact same handler method can take either a few seconds to complete or a couple of milliseconds to complete.

My problem is that I can only give the handler method one signature, and I've defined it as returning `Callable<Foo>`. I can't figure out how to kill this overhead for the short requests; as it stands, I'd create a `Callable<Foo>`, enqueue it behind long-running tasks and wait for a thread in the thread pool to get its hands on it, and all to eventually serve the response I already had in hand. I'd like to avoid all this.

If I use a `DeferredResult<Foo>` instead of a `Callable<Foo>`, things get a bit better performance-wise, but I've taken the processing out of a Spring managed thread, lost Spring Security's SecurityContext, and have polluted non-web code with the Spring-specific `DeferredResult`.

Is there an efficient way to sometimes serve responses asynchronously and sometimes serve them synchronously from the same MVC handler method?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution is quite simple. If the handler method returns `Object`, Spring determines what to do with the result based on its type. It correctly triggers asynchronous processing if the return value is a `Callable<Foo>`, and returns the result immediately otherwise, avoiding the asynchronous processing overhead when the cached result is already in hand.